# Express Router Regex - How do I use dot (.) in regex?

Tags: regex, express

I'm trying to match bcrypt's 60 digit hash in my Express router.

```
app.get('/activate-account/:hash(^\$2[ayb]\$.{56}$)', ...)
```

I was struggling to figure out why the above code wasn't matching, then I read Express Docs and it says that the dot `.` is matched literally.  However, I need to use the dot to match my bcrypt hash.

How do I use the dot regex notation in my Express app's router regex?

Comment: Does this solve your issue. May be you just need to encode the dot
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-retain-special-characters-in-expressjs-router-url-request/

Comment: Try `[\s\S]`, it is usually used to mimick the dot behavior.

Comment: @RyszardCzech Yes, that solution works for my intended use case.

Comment: Please kindly upvote my answer below since it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
[\s\S]
```

instead of the dot.

That matches any possible characters, as it means "both whitespace and non-whitespace".